# How to solve javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException?

Tags: java, sendmail

I try to send mail using below code but I am getting Exception like.

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:306)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at mail.MailTest.sendMailSSL(MailTest.java:116)
```

Please any one help me how can I solve it.

Here is my code.Thanks

```
String mailBODY = "<h3>Hi this is my test Mail</h3>;

        final String username = "username@gmail.com";
        final String password = "password";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new GMailAuthenticator(username, password));

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("TEST"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(test@gmail.com));
            message.setSubject("Mail subject test");
            message.setContent(mailBODY,"text/html; charset=utf-8");

            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("mail has been send");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding props and sending like this:

```
            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
            props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
            props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
// ...
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
// ...

Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, from, pass);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
```

Comment: Thanks urir for ur answer but same exception, I found

Comment: In this case it leaves 2 possible reasons: 1. Your user/pass wrong. recheck it. 2. Your mail server has some throttling mechanism to reject your login. Try contacting Gmail support to ask why they blocked you. Because the only fact is that the login is rejected by Gmail (it looks like this is your mail provider)

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after I enabled 2-step verification on my google account